# how does replacing $x$ with $x-h^2t$ where $h=h(x,t)$ transform an equation?

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics

I'm working on modelling a drip running down a wall, which is modelled at $t=0$

by

$h=1+e^{-x^2}$

And as $t$ increases, I've found it to be modelled by

$h=1+e^{-(x-h^2t)^2}$

Obviously, subbing $h$ into itself doesn't help whatsoever

I want to sketch how the drop would look like, and how far down the wall it would be at $t=0,1,2,3$ to illustrate what's happening. I'm also asked why this model might break down...

The obvious thing I can see is that its shifted $h^2t$ to the right, but of course, $h$ depends on $x,t$ which confuses me.

Any help with how this transformation makes the drip behave would be massively appreciated 
[image: here is the full question]

Comment: Is $h$ the distance from the wall to the surface of the drop? And is the $h$ in the transform the full $h(x,t)$ or the thin-film parameter, the "fluid depth" away from the droplet?

Comment: @David yes h is the distance from the wall, and in the transform, its the full h too

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be substituting this transformation into a differential equation?

Comment: My lecturer said its just illustrating how a sketch of that would look. When you sketch the $1+e^{-x^2}$ that's the drop at t=0 and that sketch is quite obvious. A bell curve

Comment: I was also told that this new transformation might explain how the model breaks down

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it very well David, I've posted the original question (question 2 part (e) is what I'm stuck on). Hope thats clearer

Comment: I don't really know how to answer that question, I haven't seen something like this before. Here's some Matlab code to plot the solutions though, which might be helpful: `x=-5:.05:60;f=@(s) 1+exp(-s.^2);[t,h]=ode45(@(t,h) -h.^2.*repelem(diff(h)/dx,[2 ones(1,length(x)-2)]),[0 10],f(x));plot(x,h(1:ceil(length(t)/10):end,:))` (f is the initial shape)

Comment: @David I used the code you gave me in MatLab earlier today, but you missed out defining what $dx$ was, so I just chose $dx=0.05$. A very pretty graph came up, and I was very pleased with the solution. Think about a wave of the form $h=h(x-ct)$ which obviously travels to the right at a constant speed $c$. Then a wave $h=h(x-h^2t$ travells to the right at speed $h^2$, meaning the particles further away from $x=0$ travel faster than those lower down, so the wave starts to topple over itself (like a wave in the ocean). This is why the model breaks down, since $h$ only has one output.

Comment: $h$ only can have one output, but when the wave topples, there exists an $x$value that corresponds to 2, and then 3 $h$ values. And this is where it breaks down. Thanks for the brilliant coding, really helped a lot.

Comment: Great stuff, yeah must have missed `dx`.